# dplyr filter and for loop in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, filter, dplyr

All data structures are data frames.
I've written using dplyr syntax in R.
I want replace this code with for loop.

```
rbind(
query0226 %>% 
  filter(t1.cate == tb0226_cate_below_100$Var1[1]) %>% select(t1.query, t1.cate),
query0226 %>% 
  filter(t1.cate == tb0226_cate_below_100$Var1[2]) %>% select(t1.query, t1.cate),
query0226 %>% 
  filter(t1.cate == tb0226_cate_below_100$Var1[3]) %>% select(t1.query, t1.cate),
query0226 %>% 
  filter(t1.cate == tb0226_cate_below_100$Var1[4]) %>% select(t1.query, t1.cate),
query0226 %>% 
  filter(t1.cate == tb0226_cate_below_100$Var1[5]) %>% select(t1.query, t1.cate),
query0226 %>% 
  filter(t1.cate == tb0226_cate_below_100$Var1[6]) %>% select(t1.query, t1.cate)
)
```

So I wrote the code below but it does not work.
Which part is wrong?

```r
for (i in 1:length(tb0226_cate_below_100$Var1)){
  rbind(
    query0226 %>% 
      filter(t1.cate == tb0226_cate_below_100$Var1[i]) %>% select(t1.query, t1.cate)
  )
}
```

Comment: But why would you want to do that? Perhaps I'm missing the point but instead of `rbind`ing subsets of `query0226` that you want to keep, wouldn't it be a lot faster (and tidier) to filter out entries that you don't want to keep? That would also eliminate the need for this somewhat awkward `for` loop. Again, perhaps I misunderstood but this seems like a very un-`tidyverse`-like way of doing things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
temp <- data.frame()
for (i in unique(tb0226_cate_below_100$Var1)){
  temp = rbind(temp, query0226 %>% filter(t1.cate == i) %>% select(t1.query,t1.cate))
}
```

and now `temp` is the final dataframe. You can remove the `unique` if `Var1` has only unique records.

Verified it with `mtcars` dataset

```
rbind(
   mtcars %>% filter(cyl ==4) %>% select(mpg, disp), 
   mtcars %>% filter(cyl ==6) %>% select(mpg, disp), 
   mtcars %>% filter(cyl ==8) %>% select(mpg, disp)
)

temp <- data.frame()
for (i in unique(mtcars$cyl)){
   temp = rbind(temp,mtcars %>% filter(cyl==i) %>% select(mpg, disp))
}
```